# Create new variable and then filter according to the new variable

Tags: variables, sas

I have just started using SAS recently. I am attempting to create a new table `newtable` based on another table `oldtable`.
Let's say the `oldtable` contains variable `OldPrice`. I want to create `newtable` with a new variable `NewPrice` calculated based on `OldPrice`. Then filter the `newtable` to only show `NewPrice` which is larger than 10.

Below is the sample code I have.

```
data newtable;
set oldtable;
NewPrice = OldPrice * 2
where NewPrice > 10;
run;
```

However, I receive error message saying that `NewPrice` is not a variable of `oldtable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHERE operates on the data before it reaches the data step. To conditional delete an observation once it is already in a data step you need to use IF.

For exameple just use a subsetting IF instead of WHERE.

```
data newtable;
  set oldtable;
  NewPrice = OldPrice * 2;
  if NewPrice > 10;
run;
```

Or explicitly delete the observations you don't want.

```
data newtable;
  set oldtable;
  NewPrice = OldPrice * 2;
  if NewPrice <= 10 then delete;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

A `WHERE` statement expression can only use variables in the program data vector (PDV) that come from a `SET` statement.

The data set option `WHERE=` can be used in the specification of an input or output data set.

**Statement**

```
data want;
  set have;
  where expression;
  ...
```

**Option**

```
data want;
  set have(where=(expression));
  ...
```

or

```
data want(where=(expression));
  set have;
  ...
```